# Effective way to extract related column (if any) to NpgsqlException or other Constraints violations

Tags: c#, nhibernate, npgsql

Hi everybody and thanks for reading.

I'm working with NHibernate and PostgreSQL, and basically I want to do two things:

1. Provide user-friendly messages to errors while persisting the entities in the database
2. Adapt the UI to show the errors in the specific parts (so if the name must be Unique and the user introduced one that already exists, I'd like to show the error as a tooltip of the Name textbox or whatever it is).

So I thought that finding the column where the constraint checks fails would be useful, and I'm trying to find a clean way to do this. 
For example, NHibernate throws PropertyValueException when a field fails a "Not Null" constraint, and this (exception) class has a property called "PropertyName" which tells me the property that failed the constraint. This is what I want to get, but getting the column sounds easier and I think I could get the related property from the column name.

So, is there a (clean) way to extract the related column from NpgsqlException? Or something like that using NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the hook ISqlExceptionConverter which is meant for this. Configure it with

```
config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.SqlExceptionConverter, typeof(MyNpgSqlExceptionConverter));
```

or

```
using NHibernate.Cfg.Loquacious;

config.DataBaseIntegration(d => d.ExceptionConverter<MyNpgSqlExceptionConverter>());
```

and implement it like this

```
class MyNpgSqlExceptionConverter : ISQLExceptionConverter
{
    public Exception Convert(AdoExceptionContextInfo adoExceptionContextInfo)
    {
        var npgsqlException = (NpgsqlException)adoExceptionContextInfo.SqlException;

        switch (npgsqlException.Code)
        {
            case "<errorcode for duplicate key>":
                return new WhateverException(...);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Firo. This is what I'm doing. The problem is I'd like to know what column is affected by, say, a constraint exception. NpgsqlException has this information, but only in the exception message, so I would have to parse that (localized) message to know what constraint was violated. I was reading a suggestion using a specific constraint name, so I think that is what I'll have to do, but I don't know how to tell NHibernate what name a constraint should have (don't think it's possible)

Comment: `Map(x => x.Name).UniqueKey("MyConstraintName");`

Comment: Hmm, I think I have a problem, though. My initial intention was to handle specifically a Unique Constraint Violation, and this seem to be a bit problematic. I can't assign a custom constraint name to a Unique Constraint (it's a known issue). Looks like I'll have to manually check if the 'unique' field exists in the database just before commiting

Comment: i personally would favor checking before inserting because it is easier to port to other sql dbs and makes (audit) triggers easier.

Comment: The only problem is that there could be a little risk of not catching the 'unique violation' in case of concurrency, and I don't think it's worth locking the table. But yes, I still think that's the most effective way to inform the user what caused the error.
Thanks for your help